# Creating a grid layout of elements with indefinite height

Tags: css, sass, grid

There's a simple layout made with flexbox:

```css
.elements {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.first, .second, .third {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-column {
  width: 30%;
}

.first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background: teal;
}

.second {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: crimson;
}

.third {
  width: 60%;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class='elements'>
  <div class='left-column'>
      <div class='first'>
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class='second'>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='third'>3</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create the same with grid, if elements 2 and 3 will have indefinite height because it will be calculated according to the number of their children?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is  possible to replace the above with grid.

You need to keep the row property of the grid as auto for the second row:

`grid-template-rows: 75px auto;`

And you need to extend the third element to two rows:

```
.third {
   grid-row:1/3;
  grid-column:2/3;
}
```

With your grid finally looking something like this:

```
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 60%;
  grid-template-rows: 75px auto;
}
```